# Floating-point value from bytes reading completely wrong - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point

I am attempting to read a 32-bit IEEE-754 float from a buffer, but it is not reading correctly at all. For example, `[00 00 00 3f]` becomes `8.828180325246348e-44` instead of 0.5. I have also noticed that negative floats never convert properly. For example, `[00 00 20 c1]` becomes `1.174988762336359e-41`, not -10.0.  What am I doing wrong? Is this some floating-point precision issue? This is my code:

```js
function readFloat() {
    const value = this.data.readFloatBE(this.offset);
    this.offset += 4;
    return value;
}
```

`this.data` being a `Buffer`, `this.offset` being the offset currently read in bytes.

One thing to note is that even with something like this in vanilla JavaScript, I get the same results:

```js
function floatFromBytes(bytes) {
    buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    v = new DataView(buf);
    bytes.forEach((b, i) => {
        v.setUint8(i, b);
    })
    return v.getFloat32(0);
}
floatFromBytes([0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0xc1]);  // should be -0.5, but is 1.174988762336359e-41
```

**EDIT**: Resolved, turns out the bytes were reversed for some reason.
New code:

```js
function readFloat() {
    // This is a bit of a weird IEEE 754 float implementation, but it works
    let buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    let view = new DataView(buf);
    let bytes = this.readBytes(4);
    // reverse the bytes
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        view.setUint8(i, bytes[3 - i]);
    }
    return view.getFloat32(0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you torturing yourself with that `bytes[3 - i]`? Just do `for (let i=3; i>=0; i--) ...` then just read `bytes[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted this is just an [endian issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Different systems expect bytes to be ordered in different ways, the most common ordering at the moment is little endian (used by Intel x86 compatible processors, and ARM systems are commonly set to use this mode).

Because JavaScript tries to be CPU agnostic it asks you to choose which order you want to interpret things.  The `BE` in `Buffer.readFloatBE` stands for big-endian, and there's also a `LE` version which is what you probably want to use.

For example:

```
Buffer.from('0000003f','hex').readFloatLE()  // =>   0.5
Buffer.from('000020c1','hex').readFloatLE()  // => -10.0
```